# Cannot read property 'onLaunched' of undefined in Kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, kiosk-mode

I want to detect Google Chrome kiosk mode. I am using this code to detect kiosk mode.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function (launchData) {

            alert("chrome");
            launchData.isKioskSession; //true or false
        });
```

I am getting this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLaunched' of undefined**

Do I need to add some reference?

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle#launch_data

It says:

> Depending on how your app is launched, you may need to handle launch
>   data in your event page. By default, there is no launch data when the
>   app is started by the app launcher. For apps that have file handlers,
>   you need to handle the launchData.items parameter to allow them to be
>   launched with files.

I believe you need to check if launchData object is present first.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function (launchData) {
  alert("chrome");
  if(typeof launchData !== 'undefined') {
    // Perform actions with launchData
    launchData.isKioskSession; //true or false
  }
});
```

Comment: i am not getting it property

Comment: In documentation is said that your event listener won't get launchData object when app is started by the app launcher. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onLaunched' of undefined" means that launchData is undefined which is the same as not present.

Comment: still not working..i have tried jquery fullscreen detect code.that is also does not work

Comment: the problem is that `chrome.app.runtime` doesn't have a `onLaunched` member so anything starting with `chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(...` will fail.

Answer (score -1):

The code that you listed will work if you are running in a Chrome app. If you are running in a Chrome browser launched with the --kiosk option then `chrome.app.runtime` will be undefined.

The --kiosk option is functionally equivalent to running in fullscreen mode, and you can use the [Fullscreen API](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen) to detect that.

```
var fullscreenEnabled = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled;
```

I don't know of a way to detect the --kiosk option directly.